# Как сделать что бы чекбокс работал?

Tags: html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть чекбокс, стилизованный под кнопку переключения. Но по какой то причине если ему задать атрибут "for" то сама  кнопка перестает быть анимированной, но зато функцию выполнят. Как сделать что бы все работало?

```css
.checkbox-google {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  user-select: none;
}

.checkbox-google .checkbox-google-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #9f9f9f;
  transition: .2s;
}

.checkbox-google .checkbox-google-switch:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -1px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  transition: .15s;
}

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox] {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox]:checked+.checkbox-google-switch {
  background: #9ABEF7;
}

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox]:checked+.checkbox-google-switch:before {
  background: #1a73e8;
  transform: translateX(18px);
}


/* Hover */

.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)+.checkbox-google-switch {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}


/* Active/Focus */

.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):active+.checkbox-google-switch:before,
.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):focus+.checkbox-google-switch:before {
  animation: checkbox-active-on 0.5s forwards linear;
}

@keyframes checkbox-active-on {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(212, 212, 212, 0);
  }
  99% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.5);
  }
}

.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):checked:active+.checkbox-google-switch:before,
.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):checked:focus+.checkbox-google-switch:before {
  animation: checkbox-active-off 0.5s forwards linear;
}

@keyframes checkbox-active-off {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(154, 190, 247, 0);
  }
  99% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(154, 190, 247, 0.5);
  }
}


/* Disabled */

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox]:disabled+.checkbox-google-switch {
  filter: grayscale(60%);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox]:disabled+.checkbox-google-switch:before {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-google">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="checkbox-google-switch"></span>
  Кнопка без "for"
</label>

<label class="checkbox-google" for="check-5">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="checkbox-google-switch"></span>
  Кнопка с "for"
</label>

<div class="check">
  <input type="checkbox" value="5" class="" checked id="check-5">
  <label for="check-5">Чекбокс</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас чекбоксы уже прописаны внутри меток, через `for="check-5"` Вы переопределяете чекбокс, которому соответствует эта метка, а стили у Вас завязаны на внутренний чекбокс.

Демонстрация переопределения:

```js
const f = document.getElementById('first');
const s = document.getElementById('second');
const ch = document.getElementById('check-5');
f.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('\n--------Кнопка без "for"--------\n');
  console.log('Кнопка без "for" ', f.checked);
  console.log('Кнопка с "for" ', s.checked);
  console.log('Чекбокс ', ch.checked);
});
s.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('\n--------Кнопка с "for"--------\n');
  console.log('Кнопка без "for" ', f.checked);
  console.log('Кнопка с "for" ', s.checked);
  console.log('Чекбокс ', ch.checked);
});
ch.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('\n--------Чекбокс--------\n');
  console.log('Кнопка без "for" ', f.checked);
  console.log('Кнопка с "for" ', s.checked);
  console.log('Чекбокс ', ch.checked);
});
```

```css
.checkbox-google {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  user-select: none;
}

.checkbox-google .checkbox-google-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #9f9f9f;
  transition: .2s;
}

.checkbox-google .checkbox-google-switch:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -1px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  transition: .15s;
}

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox] {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox]:checked+.checkbox-google-switch {
  background: #9ABEF7;
}

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox]:checked+.checkbox-google-switch:before {
  background: #1a73e8;
  transform: translateX(18px);
}


/* Hover */

.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)+.checkbox-google-switch {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}


/* Active/Focus */

.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):active+.checkbox-google-switch:before,
.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):focus+.checkbox-google-switch:before {
  animation: checkbox-active-on 0.5s forwards linear;
}

@keyframes checkbox-active-on {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(212, 212, 212, 0);
  }
  99% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.5);
  }
}

.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):checked:active+.checkbox-google-switch:before,
.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):checked:focus+.checkbox-google-switch:before {
  animation: checkbox-active-off 0.5s forwards linear;
}

@keyframes checkbox-active-off {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(154, 190, 247, 0);
  }
  99% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(154, 190, 247, 0.5);
  }
}


/* Disabled */

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox]:disabled+.checkbox-google-switch {
  filter: grayscale(60%);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox]:disabled+.checkbox-google-switch:before {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-google">
    <input type="checkbox" id="first">
    <span class="checkbox-google-switch"></span>
  Кнопка без "for"
</label>

<label class="checkbox-google" for="check-5">
    <input type="checkbox" id="second">
    <span class="checkbox-google-switch"></span>
  Кнопка с "for"
</label>

<div class="check">
  <input type="checkbox" value="5" class="" checked id="check-5">
  <label for="check-5">Чекбокс</label>
</div>
```

Comment: То есть не получится что бы при нажатии на один, срабатывало сразу два и при этом стили работали?

Comment: Я понял, получается при статус меняет то только чекбокс который прописан, а тот который кнопочка он как был деактивирован, так и остался. Тогда мне их просто как то связать между собой нужно, что бы при клике на один срабатывал и второй.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот таким образом:

```css
.checkbox-google {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  user-select: none;
}

.checkbox-google .checkbox-google-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #9f9f9f;
  transition: .2s;
}

.checkbox-google .checkbox-google-switch:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -1px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  transition: .15s;
}

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox] {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox]:checked+.checkbox-google-switch {
  background: #9ABEF7;
}

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox]:checked+.checkbox-google-switch:before {
  background: #1a73e8;
  transform: translateX(18px);
}


/* Hover */

.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)+.checkbox-google-switch {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}


/* Active/Focus */

.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):active+.checkbox-google-switch:before,
.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):focus+.checkbox-google-switch:before {
  animation: checkbox-active-on 0.5s forwards linear;
}

@keyframes checkbox-active-on {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(212, 212, 212, 0);
  }
  99% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.5);
  }
}

.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):checked:active+.checkbox-google-switch:before,
.checkbox-google input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled):checked:focus+.checkbox-google-switch:before {
  animation: checkbox-active-off 0.5s forwards linear;
}

@keyframes checkbox-active-off {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(154, 190, 247, 0);
  }
  99% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(154, 190, 247, 0.5);
  }
}


/* Disabled */

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox]:disabled+.checkbox-google-switch {
  filter: grayscale(60%);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.checkbox-google input[type=checkbox]:disabled+.checkbox-google-switch:before {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-google">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="checkbox-google-switch"></span>
  Кнопка без "for"
</label>

<label class="checkbox-google" for="check-6">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-6" onclick="(el = document.getElementById('check-5')).checked = !el.checked">
    <span class="checkbox-google-switch"></span>
  Кнопка с "for"
</label>

<div class="check">
  <input type="checkbox" value="5" class="" id="check-5">
  <label for="check-5">Чекбокс</label>
</div>
```